# Connect to the second NIC of a remote PC and remotely configure router

Tags: routing, router, ipv4, traceroute

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend helping me.
I have set up a testing environment with the following structure:

```
    __________                   __________               _____________
   |          |                 |          |             |             |
   |Router to | == Ethernet ==> |    PC 1  | == WiFi ==> | Main Modem/ | ==> Internet
   |configure |                 |          |             | Router      |
   |__________|                 |__________|             |_____________|
    192.168.0.1              Eth: 192.168.0.9             192.168.10.254
                             WiFi: 192.168.10.80

                                         AND
     _______               ______________________
    |       |             |                      |
    |  PC 2 | == WiFi ==> | Main Modem/Router    | ==> Internet
    |       |             | (the same as before) |
    |_______|             |______________________|
    192.168.10.188            192.168.10.254
```

I need to connect to the "Router to Configure" (192.168.0.1) from "PC 2" (192.168.10.118). I already enabled IP Routing on "PC 1" (The one with two NICs) and running `ip-config -all` returns `Routing IP Enabled: Yes`.

Then I set up a route on "PC 2" with `route add 192.168.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.10.80 metric 1` and it returned `OK`.

If connect to 192.168.0.1 from "PC 1", it correctly shows the Router configuration page, but it won't work from "PC 2". So I launched `tracert 192.168.0.1` from "PC 2" to see what was going on and the result was:

```
1  5ms   *    13ms    PC1 [192.168.10.80]
2  *     *    *       Request timeout
3  *     *    *       Request timeout
.
.
.
30  *    *    *       Request timeout
```

I don't know how I can solve it, and I googled many times in vain. There is surely something I miss.
Being this a testing environment, I have complete access to every router and PC listed above, so I can modify everything needed. If I manage to get this working, I will apply the same structure but with VPN inbetween PCs (which will no longer be on the same network)

I hope you can help me, and thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange topology... However in my opinion you have to add route on "Router to configure" for 192.168.10.X network pointing to PC1 ( 192.168.0.9).

Comment: Thank you, your solutions solved the problem. I forgot that the router has to answer to the request and so needs a route in the opposite direction (pointing to PC2). As you said, this topology is strange and exists only for tests: in reality my company will start configuring PLC (that won't answer and so won't need this route) remotely, allowing us to configure the PLCs from the headquarter, reducing by far the expenses.